# There's a way ubuntu's kernel supports my video card?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kernel, compatibility, gpu-driver

Well my problem is my old gaming laptop is not compatible with the ubuntu kernel, (as far as i read) that happened since i upgraded to ubuntu 13.10, my video card is an ***ATI Radeon HD 3650*** and each time i wanted to upgrade the driver a window pop-out and said the card is not compatible, now ubuntu 13.04 is no longet supported and i cant install the drivers, so theres a way i could install the drivers on ubuntu 14.04? because my laptop overheat without it.(sorry about my bad english)/ The specs of the laptop are:

```
Processor   Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU T4200 @ 2.00GHz    
Manufacturer    Intel    
Speed   2.0 GHz    
Number of Cores 2    
CPU ID  BFEBFBFF0001067A    
Family  06    
Model   17    
Stepping    A    
Revision    07    
Video Card  ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3650    
Manufacturer    ATI    
Chipset ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3650    
Dedicated Memory    512 MB    
Total Memory    1.7 GB    
Pixel Shader Version    4.1    
Vertex Shader Version   4.1    
Hardware T & L  Yes    
Vendor ID   1002    
Device ID   9591    
Plug and Play ID    VEN_1002&DEV_9591&SUBSYS_3A2817AA&REV_00    
Driver Version  8.970.100.1100    
Memory  3.1 GB    
Operating System    Microsoft Windows 7 Professional Edition Service Pack 1 (build 7601), 64-bit    
Service Pack    1    
Size    64 Bit    
Edition Professional    
Version 6.1.7601    
Locale  080A    
BIOS    Ver 1.00    
Version LENOVO 11CN85WW    
Manufacturer    LENOVO    
Date    10/31/08    
Display Maximum Resolution  1440 x 900    
Sound Device 1  Realtek High Definition Audio    
Driver Version  6.0.1.7246    
Sound Device 2  AVerMedia A317 Mini-Card Hybrid Analog/ATSC    
Driver Version  1.3.64.76    
Sound Device 3  AMD High Definition Audio Device    
Driver Version  7.12.0.7708
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar predicament, I've got an integrated 4000 series and in order for it to work correctly, I needed to install 12.04 LTS and install the beta driver from [AMD's Website](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/latest-linux-beta-driver.aspx) and run that. I believe that after you install the driver you can perform an upgrade using the upgrade manager and run that. But to be safe, after the install I'd install the driver again before restarting.

Comment: I did that but no luck, the system keeps crashing and the desktop is gone